# Phone number validation with letters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, regex

I need a regular expression that will accept a phone number with numbers and letters like 800callnow or something. Can anyone help?

```
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^07([\d]{3})[(\D\s)]?[\d]{3}[(\D\s)]?[\d]{3}$")]
    [Display(Name = "Phone")]
    public string Content2 { get; set; }
```

that is my validation now and of course it is incorrect..valid numbers would be like 3305323422 (330)335-2343 (330)call-now and could have a one or zero too.

Comment: Could you provide samples of valid and invalid phone numbers?

Comment: edited the question with valid numbers.

Comment: Well, it's pretty much anything. =)

Comment: Please, test this pattern: `^\(?\d{3}\)?((\d{3}\-?\d+)|\w+)$`

Comment: At the moment, something as trivial as ^[\w\s()-]+ would work... Is this really want you're looking for, or do you want to provide more strict rules on what constitutes a valid number??

Comment: @AndreCalil soo close. it works for the most part except for accepting the dashes and the ()

Comment: @CoreyToolis Could you give me an example that is not accepted? I've tested with dashes and ()

Comment: @AndreCalil `-` isn't part of `\w` so that regex shouldn't match number that include letters and a dash, that is probably the test case he is refering to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one I came up with:

```
@"^(([\d]{3}-?)|([(][\d]{3}[)]))?[\d\w]{3}([\d\w]-|-[\d\w]|[\d\w])[\d\w]{3}$";
```

It matches the first three as digits only with optional quotes and the whole area code is optional (accepts 7 digit numbers as well as 10).

The next 3 characters must be alpha-numeric, and then there is an optional dash and character, character and dash, or just a character with no dash, then the final 3 characters.

This will only allow one dash with the pattern xxx-xxxx or xxxx-xxx for the last 7 characters.

Hopefully this fulfills your requirements.